# Add event handler to Html.CheckboxFor

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, eventhandler

I'm working on a project previously developed by someone else and I've worked around to not make too many changes to it since it is time sensitive. I've hit a little block though.

In the `.vbhtml` file, there is a line as follows:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(m) m.item(counter).value, New With{.id = "chkValue_" & counter})
```

This is inside a for loop so there are many of them being created inside a table. What I need to do is add an event handler to that checkbox so that it goes to a JavaScript function that I created.

After I'm done with this, I also have a dropdown list that I have the same issue with inside this same table as seen below:

```
Html.EnumDropDownListFor(Function(m) m.item(counter).PreferredLanguage, New With {.id = "ddlPrefLang_" & counter})
```

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not change the `id` attribute. Instead add a class name and use [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to handle it (e.g. in jQuery - `$('.mycheckboxclassname').change(function() { // do something });`

Comment: That last argument you're providing to `CheckBoxFor` is the HTML attributes, is it not? Event handlers for HTML elements are provided as attributes on the element, are they not?

Comment: Thank you both. Adding onclick to the checkbox HTML attributes for the checkbox and onchange to the dropdown worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up adding onclick to the HTML attributes as was suggested in the comments. The result is below:

@Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(m) m.item(counter).value, New With{.id = "chkValue_" & counter, .onclick = "*//Call function here*"})